# How to set up HP P3005x printer for double-sided printing OS X 10.9?

Tags: printing

My MacBook Pro having OS X 10.9 is connected to network printer HP LaserJet P3005x, but I can't print on both sides of the paper automatically, particularly the Word documents. Can someone guide me how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Does the printer, as you've configured it in Mavericks, show "duplex printing" as a feature?